# Correción de clase en C++ "does not name a type" constructor

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una librería para un sensor y quiero implementar algunas cosas bastante productivas que harán que el código se vea mas limpio, pero estoy ante un problema de creación. Me he basado en los modelos de librerías que he creado anteriormente.

**Pir.cpp**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Pir.h>

#define DEBUGGIN

#ifdef DEBUGGIN
#define Pir_Debug(String) Serial.println(String)
#endif

Pir::Pir(uint8_t _pin, uint16_t _SensingInterval,
         void (*_CallBackFunction)(void)) {

  this->pin = _pin;
  this->CallBackFunction = _CallBackFunction;
  this->SensingInterval = _SensingInterval;

  pinMode(pin, INPUT);
  checkCallBack();
}

void Pir::checkCallBack(void (*_CallBackFunction)(void)) {
  if (!_CallBackFunction) {
    Pir_Debug("The Pir Obj does not have a CallBackFunction");
  }
}
```

**Pir.h**

```
#ifdef PIR_H
#define PIR_H

class Pir {

private:
  uint8_t pin;
  bool state;
  uint16_t SensingInterval;

  void (*CallBackFunction)(void);

public:
  // Constructor
  Pir(uint8_t _pin, uint16_t SensingInterval = 1000,
      void (*_CallBackFunction)(void) = 0);

  void checkCallBack(void (*_CallBackFunction)(void));

  inline void CallBackFunction() {
    if (CallBackFunction)
      (*CallBackFunction)();
  }

  // Destructor
  virtual ~Pir();

  // Setters
  inline void setInterval(uint16_t _SensingInterval) {
    this->SensingInterval = _SensingInterval;
  }

  inline void setPin(uint8_t _pin) { this->pin = _pin; }

  // Getters
  inline bool getState() { return this->state; };
};

#endif
```

Este es el error cuando compila el Pir.cpp

[image: Este es el error cuando compila el Pir.cpp]

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef PIR_H
#define PIR_H
```

Ese `ifdef` debería ser `ifndef`. Lo que está sucediendo ahora es que la cabecera espera que el símbolo `PIR_H` esté definido para poder declarar `Pir`.

Por otro lado, está muy bien que tengas una compilación condicional para que en modo debug te aparezcan trazas, pero deberías tener en cuenta que el código debería seguir siendo válido si se deshabilitan dichas trazas:

```
#ifdef DEBUGGIN
#define Pir_Debug(String) Serial.println(String)
#endif 

void Pir::checkCallBack(void (*_CallBackFunction)(void))
{
  if (!_CallBackFunction)
  {
    Pir_Debug("The Pir Obj does not have a CallBackFunction");
  }
}
```

¿Que pasa si no está definido el símbolo `DEBUGGIN`? Que tendrás un error de compilación.

La solución más limpia suele ser definir `Pir_Debug` como un símbolo vacío en el caso de que `DEBUGGIN` no esté definido:

```
#ifdef DEBUGGIN
#define Pir_Debug(String) Serial.println(String)
#else
#define Pir_Debug(String) 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

Pir.h

```
#ifndef PIR_H
#define PIR_H

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define DEBUGGIN

#ifdef DEBUGGIN
#define Pir_Debug(String) Serial.println(String)
#endif


typedef void (*CallBackFunction)(void);

class Pir
{

private:
  uint8_t mPin;
  bool mState;
  uint16_t mSensingInterval;

  CallBackFunction mCallback;

public:
    Pir(uint8_t pin, uint16_t sensingInterval = 1000, CallBackFunction callback=0);

    void checkCallBack();
    // Setters
    inline void setInterval(uint16_t sensingInterval) {
        mSensingInterval = sensingInterval;
    }

    inline void setPin(uint8_t pin) { mPin = pin; }

    // Getters
    inline bool getState() { return mState; };

};

#endif // PIR_H
```

Pir.cpp

```
#include "Pir.h"

Pir::Pir(uint8_t pin, uint16_t sensingInterval, CallBackFunction callback)
{

    mPin = pin;
    mCallback = callback;
    mSensingInterval = sensingInterval;
    pinMode(mPin, INPUT);
    checkCallBack();
}

void Pir::checkCallBack() {
#ifdef DEBUGGIN
  if(mCallback) {
    Pir_Debug("The Pir Obj does not have a CallBackFunction");
  }
#endif
}
```